# Make a grid column disappear on hover

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout with 3 columns and when I hover I want that the first column disappears. I tried like this but every time it just cuts of the last one (click full page to see problem):

```css
#main {
  margin: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100px, 200px) minmax(200px, 400px) auto;
  grid-template-areas: "search results info";
}

#main:hover {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 400px) auto;
  grid-template-areas: "results info"
}

#search {
  grid-area: "search";
  background-color: lightcoral;
  height: 100px;
}

#results {
  grid-area: "results";
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#info {
  grid-area: "info";
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="main">
    <section id="search">
    </section>
    <section id="results">
    </section>
    <section id="info">
    </section>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `display:none` on hover for the non needed one and you can get rid and of the `grid-template-areas`:

```css
#main {
  margin: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100px, 200px) minmax(200px, 400px) auto;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#main:hover {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 400px) auto;
}

#main:hover #search {
  display: none;
}

#search {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

#results {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#info {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <section id="search">
  </section>
  <section id="results">
  </section>
  <section id="info">
    content
  </section>
</section>
```